# hibernate error during registration

Tags: oracle

```
Hibernate: select max(profileNumber) from User_Profile
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not fetch initial value for increment generator
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
 at 
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

 )
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
 at org.hibernate.id.IncrementGenerator.getNext(IncrementGenerator.java:85)
 ... 36 more
Updated Succesfully
Datadao.ProfileDAO@565eb0ea
```

Please help me over this problem.

Comment: sorry i didn't get your answer.